# How to use Node `http` module in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I need to write a server in TypeScript and Node.

1. I downloaded [Node](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/node/node.d.ts) from [DefinitelyTyped](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped) repository
2. I created my typescript file
3. Imported the definition
4. Tries to use it

The result is:

```
/// <reference path="definitions/commonjs.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="definitions/node.d.ts" />

var http = require("http");

namespace MyProj {
    export class Server {
        public run() {
            var server = http.createServer(); // TypeScript does not recognize 'http'
        }
    }
}
```

But I cannot understand how I can reference the `http` module. Where can I find the types? In the definition file i am having hard time recognizing this information.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

It's because of you are using `require`. use `import` instead it will recognize and also will give you nice intellisense :-)

```
import * as http from "http"
```