# Node http module is not found when using from typescript

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

```
$ node -v
v16.13.0
```

I'm very new to TS/JS and try to understand how to import modules provided by node js with typescript. Following this [`How to use Node` http `module in TypeScript`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38941636/how-to-use-node-http-module-in-typescript) QA I tried it myself and wrote the following simple typescript file:

```
import * as http from "http"
```

When running `tsc main.ts` I got the following error:

```
main.ts:1:23 - error TS2307: Cannot find module 'http' or its 
corresponding type declarations.
```

Maybe some more options are required to the tsc? I tried to add `tsc --module commonjs main.ts` but got the same error.

I thought all node js modules are visible for typescript by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is all you need to do :')

```
import { http } from "http";
```

Comment: Tried `tsc main.ts` and got the same error...

Comment: did you installed that first or not?

Comment: Install node? I did, isn't http included in nodejs?

Comment: Ah... I see now, thanks for the point. I didn't install @types/node.

Answer (score 0):

`tsc --init`

To initialize the Typescript configuration file. The error disappeared for me.